# why can not install buildozer in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I just trying to install buildozer using the following comand:

```
pip install buildozer
```

But always turn me back the following error:

> root@android-HP-ProBook-6550b:/home/android# pip install buildozer
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in
>   
>       from pip import main ImportError: cannot import name main

WHat i'm doing wrong and why can not install buildozer in ubuntu.